# How to airflow variable with value containing foreign characters?

Tags: variables, character-encoding, character, airflow, encode

I am trying to create an Airflow variable from the UI with the value containing foreign characters.  The Airflow variable is created successfully but the value is shown as invalid and the content/value is removed.
Below is an example of the variable value:

```
{
  "greeting": "你好"
}
```

Does Airflow support Airflow variables with values containing foreign characters?  Is there a configuration change in `airflow.cfg` that can allow this without having to change the Airflow code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried specifying your string with u"你好"?

Comment: Possibly a Bug, suggest asking on the Airflow Slack #troubleshooting channel. 
https://apache-airflow-slack.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thank you, zhqiat.  I had try that.  I ended up converting the string to Unicode.  Bjorn, it does seem like a bug, I'll try the the airflow slack channel.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow supports `UTF-8` by default but you can set it by changing environment variable `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ENGINE_ENCODING` or changing `sql_engine_encoding` in `airflow.cfg` (see [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/configurations-ref.html#sql-engine-encoding))

I'm having no trouble with creating such variable in Airflow 1.10.14[image]